# Excel VBA: Enabling Macro Settings

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro method to auto-size the columns in an Excel sheet upon opening the sheet. However, this solution does not work in the case that the user has not enabled macros in Excel.

Is there any way to check if the user has VBA macros disabled in Excel, and then enable the macros with Excel VBA code?

Answer (score 14):

The standard way of doing this is to force the user to enable macros by use of a splash screen.

- All the sheets in the workbook except for a spash screen are made
  *very hidden* (which can only be changed via VBA or the VBA editor)
- if macros are enabled:
  1) When the workbook opens, the code unhides all these *very hidden* sheets
  2) When the workbook closes then all these sheets are made *very hidden* again
- If macros are not enabled then the user can only see the Splash Screen saying "Please enable macros, close and then re-open this file"

Two links with full code for this technique are listed below

1. Brad Yundt covers this [here at TekTips](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=923923)
2. Jonske [at VBAeXpress](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=578)

Comment: I'd opt for something like the first link above, as it uses BeforeSave.  The problem with using BeforeClose is that the user may have made changes which they don't want to save, a choice which is overridden by saving the workbook in the BeforeClose event, as in the 2nd link.  One other thing is that you need to handle any sheets that are supposed to be hidden or, if it's possible for them to do so, were hidden by the user.

Comment: Brad Yundt's code (link #1 above, bottom of page) almost works, but not quite.  It does not pass all 6 test cases below.  For each test: Open the file, enable macros, and do the test.  PASS = no odd behaviour and file closes quiety.  Tests: (1) ... do nothing, close. (2) ... type into cell, close, say NO at save prompt.  (3) ... type into cell, close, say YES at save prompt. (4) ... type into cell, save, close.  (5) ... type into cell, close, say CANCEL at save prompt, save, close.  (6) ... type into cell, close, CANCEL at prompt, save, type into another cell, close, YES at prompt.

Comment: I've finally got code that passes all 6 test cases.  The code incorporates @brettdj's ideas above, [Brad Yundt's codes](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=923923), and two posts from John Walkenbach [#1](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip78.htm), [#2](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip100.htm).  Since this post is now 2 years old, leaving a note for future readers.  If this is still of interest, feel free to get in touch.

Comment: @AssadEbrahim Would you mind posting your code as an answer? I'd love to see how you did that.

Comment: @ZX9 Sure, I've posted it [on my site here.](http://mathscitech.org/articles/downloads)  Click on Source Code Listings.  Item #6  Enable Macros (VBA Source Code)  Tested & works on Excel 2007.  Feedback welcomed.  Email's in the code header.

Answer (score 4):

This is a security feature. If you could disable it within Excel in vba it would defeat the purpose.
I'm afraid the answer is no, the user will need to adapt his security settings...

That being said, you could change the settings from another application by modifying the registry. On recent versions of Office, this is the key that defines the behaviour: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\XXXX\Excel\Security` where you need to modify (or create) a DWORD named `vbawarnings`. The values it can take are as follows ([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f091b658-4a71-4f12-bd2d-aea9ac53a65d/enable-ms-excel-macrodisable-excel-macro-warning?forum=Office2016ITPro)):

- 1: Enable all macros (not recommended)
- 2: Disable all with notification
- 3: Disable all except digitally signed macros
- 4: Disable all without notification

Comment: +1 for the registry approach. I have tried this before with a [tag:vbs] and it worked ok on the local machine, this is probably also doable over a local network by connecting to other machines. But a remote user would need to run the code themselves to set the macro settings, so given approval is needed I go the splash screen route.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yup, and no idea what was there - I should have given more details in my answer... I've updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternate method to check if VBA is enabled without having to hide/show sheets. The problem with hiding/unhiding sheets is that the worksheet could be saved in an "enabled" state, be closed without saving, and then be re-opened and not display the warning.

Create the following function in a Module (not a worksheet or workbook macro):

```
Public Function MacrosEnabled()
    MacrosEnabled = True
End Function
```

Now, in whatever cell you want to display a notice regarding whether macros are enabled or not, enter the following equation:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MacrosEnabled()&NOW()),"Macros are disabled","Macros are enabled")
```

If you just use `ISERROR(MacrosEnabled())` the value is not recalculated every time the spreadsheet is opened. By concatenating `NOW()`, the current time is read every time the spreadsheet is opened, and so the value of the cell is recalculated. I tested this method extensively, and it seems to very reliably indicate whether macros are enabled or not.

You can then apply conditional formatting to do a number of things if macros are disabled:

- Highlight the check-cell in a bright color, and perhaps change the "macros are disabled" text to include instructions on how to enable macros.
- "Hide" cells whose values depend on macros being enabled by setting their text color and background color to be the same.

[Here is a spreadsheet that demonstrates this method](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt89grsx5mc87um/macro_check_demo.xlsm?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to automate the macro enabling, but you need to have full control on client machine at least once. Use digital certificates and sign your macros with it, the first time you run macros signed, Excel will offer to you an option to always trust macros signed by this certificate. When you trust it, all macros signed with your certificate will be automatically enabled.

This is the best option to develop and manage macros on your corporate network.