# Opening Excel spreadsheets maximized

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

for a better user experience, I would like to make a spreadsheet downloaded from the web maximized when it is opened through the user's desktop MS Excel 2010 program.

Can this be achieved through preference configuration or is there Macro involved?

Thanks!
Che

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a simple macro to do what you ask. You need to put it in the workbook module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized 'maximize Excel
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized 'maximize the workbook in Excel
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie. Simple and elegant. Cheers.

Comment: Jamie, one more question. This works in the desktop environment, but when it comes to downloading the spreadsheet from the web, it wouldnt work and I suppose this has to do with the user's security settings. Is there any workaround?

Comment: One option might be to display a "splash screen" until the user enables macros. As far as I know, there's no way of maximising the application without using macros. An answer here explains splash screens http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421843/excel-vba-enabling-macro-settings

Answer (score -2):

1. open excel from start menu
2. when excel is launched, maximized the window. At the time , the excel without any document opened.
3. drag a document with extension .xls into excel
4. close the excel

Now, open any document from the explorer, you would see excel speadsheets maximized

Comment: The OP wants that it will happen automatically, without any operation that the user itself will need to perform.

Answer (score -3):

First, excuse me if I make spelling or grammar mistakes because I well know the French language, I am a Lebanese. Compared to Excel, I had the same problem, Excel (Excel 2010) can not open in Full window (maximized), I make several attempts to locate Excel, I do not manage to solve the problem and I think it issue is caused by a conflict between office and other software.

Finally, I solved the problem. How? - I have another hard drive (HDD), I installed Windows on that disk. - I installed Office (Microsoft Office) - I copied this new office Disc 2 - I erased (deleted) Disc 1 - I stuck to the Office Disc 1 The problem is solved.

Tip: For the next time, when you install Office, it is advisable to keep a copy of this office in another part of the hard drive to replace the original copy if it suffers from a problem.

Comment: Reinstalling office is not a VBA solution to maximizing a window. Only English answers are allowed on SO.