# Workbook Before Close Not Working for some but working for others

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following codes which is working for some people but not others.
The following does the reverse at opening the spreadsheet.
Could it be a setting it excel?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Control As Office.CommandBarControl

Application.CommandBars("ply").Enabled = True     'disables right-Click on 
sheet tab

For Each Control In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=21)    
'disables CUT
Control.Enabled = True
Next Control For Each Control In 
Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=19)     'disables COPY
    Control.Enabled = True
 Next Control

Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
Application.CutCopyMode = True
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely they have macros disabled so this can't work. To force them to enable macros try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9425491/7558682)

Comment: It can't be the issue. This is for work and my company automatically enable macros settings and company default.

Comment: Are all Excel versions same and with same updates installed? Same OS?

Comment: What do you mean with *"is working for some people but not others"* - is it not triggered at all or does something fail to work as expected?

Comment: *"my company automatically enables macros"* that seems like a security issue

Comment: Some either Excel 2010 or Excel 2013 but I have people on both versions that the macro works for.