# Macro to stop access to file if automatic email send doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have a macro that sends an email automatically when a file is opened per the below, however I want to make it that if it's unable to send the email that the file wont open or it comes up with a warning that then can't be dismissed? New to this so any help greatly appreciated

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim oApp As Object 'Outlook.Application 'Object
    Dim ns As Object 'Namespace
    Dim fldr As Object 'MAPIFolder
    Dim mItem As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
    Dim sendTo As Object 'Outlook.Recipient
    Dim bOutlookFound As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    bOutlookFound = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not bOutlookFound Then Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'New Outlook.Application

    '# Set the namespace and folder so you can add recipients
    Set ns = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fldr = ns.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'olFolderInbox

    '# create an outlook MailItem:
    Set mItem = oApp.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

    '# assign a recipient
    Set sendTo = mItem.Recipients.Add("receipient name")
        sendTo.Type = 1 'To olTo
    '# Validate the recipients (not necessary if you qualify valid email addresses:
    For Each sendTo In mItem.Recipients
        sendTo.Resolve
    Next

    mItem.Subject = "A user has opened the Excel file"
    mItem.Body = "This is an automated message to inform you that " & _
                 Environ("username") & " has downloaded and is using the file."

    mItem.Save
    mItem.Send

    'If outlook was not already open, then quit
    If Not bOutlookFound Then oApp.Quit

    Set oApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Tried to locate on the forums to no avail

Comment: If the user disables macros when opening the file what then?  Even if they enable on the first open, they can just close and re-open without macros...

Comment: The people using the file would likely have them enabled as a default, however in this instance they'd need to be enabled because of other macros/functionality within the file.

Comment: Essentially its to stop/deter the file being used outside the business...it may be there's a better way of doing it. Is there any way of creating a dedicated list of "users" that can open the file which can be updated for example x@x.com, y@x.com, z@x.com but not x@abc.com?

Comment: Anything you do can easily be bypassed by anyone who cares to do a quick Google search, so typically this is not time well spent, unless you're only trying to prvent honest users from making mistakes with the file.

Comment: Hide sheets until macros enabled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421843/excel-vba-enabling-macro-settings